# LTspice exception: Time step is too small in flip flop simulation

Tags: digital-logic, ltspice, simulation

I have scheme with simple JK-trigger with Reset and Preset:

[image]

But, I have error:

> Time step too small; initial timepoint; trouble with and-instance A7

(it can say any AND gate) when try to start simulation. Setting any time step throws the same exception.

What is the issue here?

UPD: Find, that crossing between A3 and A7 in /outs cause problem, but why?

Comment: Do you have any voltage sources in your simulation?

Comment: Call up the attribute editor on one of your gates and show it to me. It should look something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHf3q.png). There's also an SR in the digital folder. May want to use it.

Comment: Voltage Spike, dont have any voltage source.

Comment: periblepsis, there's nothing there, default gates.

Comment: Meh, want pure logic gates.

Comment: @Everything You have to give it something. Just use 1 and 0 for the voltage if that helps. But they don't work otherwise. Read the section called `A. Special Functions`.

Comment: Another random tip, if you put an underscore before a node label it will automatically turn it into that label with a line over it.  For example, if you use `_Q` it will show up graphically as "Q-bar".

Answer (score 2):

It helped.

> That's a convergence error. You have a race condition due to your inputs. Add different propagation delays and/or rise and fall times to the individual gates. E.g. make the Td parameter of U1 = 10n, Td of U2 = 15n, etc. You can also change the rise and fall times of your inputs, but again make them different from one another.

[Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskElectronics/comments/nidi3n/comment/gz1ogtn/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button)

Comment: Yeah. The SR present in the Digital folder circumvents this need. You can use one for the second SR you have. But your clear and preset needs complicate it. Glad to see you have something to work with, now. :) +1

Comment: I suggest in addition to `Td` that you set the `Tau` parameter too (even something small) so that it functions more like it would in real life.  It also avoids strange glitches that are generated by how LTspice's A-devices work.